# Transferring files to VMs via SSH web browser upload button

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I was wondering where the location of the files are once they are uploaded to VM instances.

I cannot find it very easily.

I am using the below menu to upload available in ssh web browser window.

[image]

**UPDATES**

I managed to find the upload path of the file uploaded(see my answer below).
But I am now having problems with downloading files. I provide the full path but was unable to download it. Is there any trick to this? 
I am using Safari Version 10.0.2 (11602.3.12.0.1)

Comment: Were you able to get the download working?  If not, does it work in other browsers?

Comment: I managed to get the upload working. It does upload files successfully which is really handy. 
I could not download a file yet& no I have not tried with other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the location.
Once the upload is done and you see the success message, the file will be in the users home directory.

The username that you have logged in via ssh web browser to upload the file.